# Where is the Google Information Rights Management API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-api-php-client

In March 2015 Information Rights Management (IRM) capabilities for Google Drive and Google Docs were announced on the [Google for Work blog](http://googleforwork.blogspot.com/2015/03/keep-all-of-your-work-more-secure-with.html).

I wondered if anyone has come across any Google Drive / Doc API's for the IRM capability?

Specifically API controls that programmatically disable downloading, printing and copying of any file?

Answer (score 0):

You can control copy, download, and print operations via the Drive REST API.

In [Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files), it can be set via the `labels.restricted` property:

> Whether viewers and commenters are prevented from downloading, printing, and copying this file.

In [Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files), it can be set via the `viewersCanCopyContent` property:

> Whether users with only reader or commenter permission can copy the file's content. This affects copy, download, and print operations.